# Change the View visibility of all items of RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView who play the recording when certain item is clicked. I want the behave when a user clicks on item1 that specific recording is playing and button View is changed which is working fine.

But at the same time when item1 recording is playing and user click on item2 then item1 row Button come back to its original position.

Below Image show the View when item1(Row 1) is clicked. (This is working fine)

I have also test this to control the View in inBindViewHolder method.But it is not working because whenever I clicked holder object control the View of current selected row only.

## Below Code Section is placed in the ViewHolder

```
mPlayAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Present in onClick mPlayAudio");
                    if (listener != null) 
                    {
                        final int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) 
                        {
                           // This section contain the code to play and stop 
                              the audio

                          // Using below line I only able to change selected 
                          // row button View not other row Button View  
                          mPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);  

                        }
                     }
                 }
});
```

I have also try this with in onBindViewHolder method but still not working.

## Below Code added in onBindViewHolder

`holder.mPlayAudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
               // This section contain code to play and stop audio
               //Using below statement I only able to change the
               //visibility of current selected row View not others
               holder.mPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
}`

Comment: If you are looking to hide the visibility of every single item then you could set a variable in your adapter. So when you click an item, it sets the boolean hideItems to true. Finally in your BindViewHolder have an if statement checking if hideItems is true, where you hide the visibility. Can't remember if you would need to refresh your dataset as well.

Comment: No, I don't want to hide every single item of RecyclerView. Actually I have a play button in every single row of RecyclerView. Whenever this button is clicked button visibility changed like shown in this image https://imgur.com/0fpk0Jv.

Comment: When user click on first row button visibility changed which is working fine. But when user click on second row button of RecyclerView I want to change the button of first row to came back to its original position. Scenario shown in this image imgur.com/n4Q26Qm

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, if I get the chance I will write out a full answer. The best option might be if your passing in a List or ArrayList with a custom data type then you can add a boolean variable "isVisibile". This way you could either iterate through all the details in this list and then set your current as "False". Thats my first thought but tomorrow I'll post an answer if nobody else does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally was able to try this out on my own project.

**Answer**
In BindViewHolder, after you have made an item click, save the value of the position of that item. Then call notifyDataSetChanged inside the click event, which will refresh the adapter. Now it obtain your result, inside BindViewHolder have an if statement checking if that value should be set accordingly (or invisible), otherwise display as visible.

**Example Code**

```
public class SelectorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectorAdapter.ItemHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

private List itemList;
private int selectedKey;

public SelectorAdapter(List list) {
    itemList = list;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}


/* ViewHolder for each item */
class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //title
    @BindView(R.id.selector_title)
    TextView title;

    @BindView(R.id.selector_layout)
    LinearLayout selector;

    ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    }
}


@Override
public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout_selector, parent, false);

    return new ItemHolder(itemView);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {

    String title = (String) itemList.get(position);

    holder.title.setText(title);

    if (position != selectedKey) {
        holder.title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
    } else {
        holder.title.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_selected);
    }


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Timber.e("selected item: %s", position);
        selectedKey = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Timber.e("itemCount: %s", itemList.size());
    return itemList.size();
}


}
```

Here is my own project where when I select an item, it changes the background resource to selected, and then the rest are returned to the default state.